# Counting the number of Parents related to a child entry

Tags: relationships

I am using the example Relationships code which works but what I would like to do instead of showing the names of the Pizza shops is just show how many shops the Pizza is available at.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pizzas"}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{description}</p>
    <p>{ingredients}</p>
    <h3>Where can I find this pizza?</h3>
    {parents field="specialty_pizzas"}
            <strong>{parents:title}</strong>: <br />
            {parents:phone} <br />
            <p>{parents:address}</p>
    {/parents}
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

I have tried this, but it does not appear to work, any hints?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pizzas"}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{description}</p>
    <p>{ingredients}</p>
    <h3>How many restaurants serve this pizza?</h3>
    {parents field="specialty_pizzas"}
            {parents:speciality_pizzas:total_results}
    {/parents}
```

{/exp:channel:entries}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
{parents field="specialty_pizzas"}
{if parents:count == "1"}{parents:total_results}{/if}
{/parents}
```

Comment: Does this work if there are other channels that also have the "pizzas" channel as a child? for me, {parents:total_results} is not returning a "filtered" number, it's returning the number of all parent entries. I just posted about it here https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41143/how-can-i-get-total-results-number-of-entries-filtered-using-the-parents-tag