# How can I get "total_results" number of entries filtered using the parents tag?

Tags: relationships, parent

I have a channel entries tag that displays one entry form the "markets" channel. Within that, I want to display article entries. The "articles"(parent) channel has a relationship field to select which "markets"(child) entry. But, I have other channels that also have a relationship field pointing to "markets" entries. So when I use the code below to display "parents" from a specific channel and field, it works fine. BUT, if that results in 3 entries being returned, the parents_total_results tag doesn't return 3, it returns a higher number. Is there any way to get a number of the entries returned from the parents tag?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="markets" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields|pagination" sort="asc" limit="1" dynamic="yes" require_entry="yes"}
        {parents field="articlemarket" channel="articles" limit="3" sort="desc" orderby="date"}
        {parents:total_results}
        {/parents}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if it's a bug. As your results total is 8, are there actually 8 parent entries across channels/entries for this particular entry?

Try this code, should pull in all parent titles:

```
{parents}
{parents:title}<br>
{if parents:count == parents:total_results}
 Total: {parents:total_results}
{/if}
{/parents}
```

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this with me! That code did display the titles of all the entries with a relationship field pointing to the market entry. It's displaying the 4 entries I want to display, as well as 4 more. So I guess this means parents:total_results either has a bug, or that is the expected outcome and it may need to be updated?

Comment: FML, I figured it out. There is a {parents:total_results} tag outside of the parents tag higher up in the template. It was finding 8 and the the value wasn't changing for the next {parents:total_results} within the parents tag pair. So removed that and things are working ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Mike have you tried removing the field= parameter? you shouldn't really need it unless you're pulling data from multiple relationship fields in the articles channel.

```
{parents channel="articles" limit="3" sort="desc" orderby="date"}
{parents:total_results}
{/parents}
```

Comment: Won't it pull any parent entries that have a relationship field pointed to the market entry though? I thought adding the field parameter prevented that from happening?

Comment: Hard to guess without knowing the full channel structure, did you try it?

Comment: If I remove the limit from the parents tag pair, it's returning 4 entries like it is supposed to. But {parents:total_results} is still returning "8". if I remove the field parameter it doesn't seem to affect things one way or the other.